# Не работает action menu activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
введите сюда код
```

````
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.opticion_menu,menu);

       return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        if (item.getItemId()==R.id.menu_find_people)
        {


        }
        if (item.getItemId()==R.id.menu_create_group)
        {


        }
        if (item.getItemId()==R.id.menu_settings)
        {
            Intent settinIntent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(settinIntent);

        }
        if (item.getItemId()==R.id.menu_logout)
        {
           mAuth.signOut();
           Intent logIntent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
           startActivity(logIntent);

        }
        return true;
    }```
Вот так прописал функции пока на две кнопки. Хотел протестировать но меню не открывается. Само меню сделал в отдельной дерективе в папке res под названием menu. Как это исправить?
````

Answer (score 0):

В твоем коде проблем не вижу. Где ты пытаешься создать меню? Если это твой собственный Toolbar, не забудь указать  setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);